# Is this true that algebraic spaces etale and surjective over a scheme is a scheme ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be an algebraic space such that there exists an etale surjective map f: X -> Y, where Y
is a scheme. Is it true that this implies X is also a scheme?

Answer (score 9):

The point must be to avoid separatedness hypotheses on $f$. (D. Knutson proved algebraic spaces locally quasi-finite and separated over schemes are schemes; he may have had noetherian hypotheses, in which case those hypotheses are removed in the appendix to Champs Algebriques.)

Anyway, in the absence of separatedness the answer is negative. In the Introduction to Knutson's book there's a procedure beginning with smooth algebraic variety $Y$ of dimension $> 1$ over a field and "replacing" a smooth hypersurface in $Y$ with an irreducible etale double cover while remaining smooth and irreducible. This resulting $X$ is an algebraic space etale over $Y$, and the rank-jumping of $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is really weird: it jumps *up* along a closed set rather than down, contrary to Zariski's Main Theorem (in the formulation of EGA) for locally quasi-finite flat maps of schemes. Hence, $X$ is not a scheme (though the failure to be a scheme can surely be seen in a zillion other ways).

The preceding does actually have an "application". It yields a geometrically irreducible smooth algebraic space $X$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ of dimension 2 such that $X_{\mathbf{C}}$ admits an analytification in the sense of complex-analytic spaces but $X_k$ does not admit an analytification in the sense of rigid-analytic spaces or Berkovich $k$-analytic spaces for any non-archimedean field $k$ of characteristic 0.  (This is explained in detail in Example 3.1.1 of my paper "Non-archimedean analytification of algebraic spaces" with M. Temkin.)

Comment: Brian, regarding your application, what goes wrong? Suppose you write $X$ as the quotient of an affine scheme $A$ by an etale equivalence relation $B$, and we write $B$ as a quotient of an affine scheme $C$ by an etale equivalence relation $D$, with $D$ affine. The most obvious way of making the analytification of $X$ would by the following steps. 1) Analytify $C$ and $D$. 2) Presumably this is an etale equivalence relation. 3) Let $B'$ be the quotient. 4) Presumably $B'$ is an etale equivalence relation on the analytification of $A$. 5) Let $X'$ be the quotient. What goes wrong?

Comment: Jim, since $B$ is a scheme, it has an analytification, and that is $B'$. We cannot just "let" something be the quotient. We have to prove a quotient (according to reasonable and useful *definition*; e.g., does indeed make $B^{\rm{an}}$ serve as $B'$) actually exists. For item 5, it doesn't exist. (Surprised? I sure was!) If you look up the reference at the end of my answer you'll see the reason that it does not exist. The dichotomy with the complex-analytic case is that there's no "Gelfand-Mazur theorem" over non-arch. fields, even alg. closed ones.

Comment: You don't have quotients by etale equivalence relations? Are you sure you've chosen the right definitions? :)

Comment: By the way, I mean the definition of the category of analytic spaces, not the definition of quotients (in response to the comment that used to be here...). I would hope that your category would be a full subcategory of some ambient topos (such as that given by the site of analytic spaces under some topology) and be closed under etale equivalence relations. I'd further hope that it would have a nice universal property along these lines, such as being the minimal subcategory containing a category of local models and closed under certain admissible equivalence relations, like with alg spaces.

Comment: Jim, even in the category of complex-analytic spaces there are etale equivalence relations admitting no quotient as such (even equivalence relations arising from analytifying etale scheme charts for algebraic spaces of finite type over $\mathbf{C}$). So do you consider the complex-analytic spaces to be an inadequate category? 

Comment: OK, that's interesting. Can you give me an example or a reference?

Comment: Jim, see Theorem 2.2.5 of my paper with Temkin for a proof that "diagonal being immersion" is a necessary condition for analytifiability (= existence of quotient for analytified etale equivalence relation) of a quasi-separated algebraic space locally of finite type over $\mathbf{C}$ (or over any non-archimedean field; same whether rigid-analytic or Berkovich). That this diagonal condition is actually *sufficient* over $\mathbf{C}$ for existence of the quotient is an instructive exercise.  At the end of my answer I give a reference for a counterexample to that over any non-archimedean field.

Comment: Thanks. After looking at an example that isn't locally separated, my inclination would be to say that complex-analytic spaces are an inadequate category. I would think that you'd want your category to have a simple universal property. Does the category of usual complex-analytic spaces have one? If not, I'd expect that you'd run into trouble when defining functors to and from your category (which actually might be happening here). Surjective local isomorphisms surely have all the descent properties you'd ever want. Why not adjoin the quotients by such equivalence relations for convenience?

Comment: Jim, so you're proposing to make a kind of complex-analytic version of the theory of algebraic spaces.  Yes, perhaps a reasonable thing, though it would be appropriate to first undertake a study of the work of Binenger et al. who carried over Artin's methods to the complex-analytic category to see what they did. I think it is nonetheless interesting to get affirmative existence results for etale quotients under some mild separatedness hypotheses, and one probably needs some genuinely compelling examples to justify serious effort towards (or interest in!) working with a bigger category.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd probably prefer to deal with the larger, simply defined category so I'm not forced to deal with technical concepts like local separatedness and so on. But I can see why other people would like to restrict to the subcategory of objects that have certain niceness properties. Thanks for the helpful discussion!

Comment: Jim, since complex-analytic spaces are locally Hausdorff, the diagonal for an analytic presentation cannot be totally wild if there's to be a quotient in the sense of analytic spaces. That may clarify matters a bit. Deligne once said (concerning the tradeoff for schemes vs. algebraic spaces) that it can be useful to have affine open nbhds. Very true, and similarly on the analytic side. Any technical gain in one aspect surely introduces technical problems elsewhere; never get something for nothing. So by going to the bigger "simply defined" category, I'm sure one creates new difficulties.

Comment: I think that you can often get something for nothing. Rather, if you have bad foundations, something that is really nothing can look like something that is something. With good foundations, what you thought was something technical is often revealed to be nothing. Surely you agree with this on some level. Otherwise, all choices of foundations would be equally good or bad.

Comment: Jim, I agree with 2nd & 3rd sentences, not the first.  To get good foundations, one has to do some real work somewhere.  For instance, one can make up the definition of algebraic spaces, but it is hard work to get that theory off the ground.  Likewise, if one wants to work with your suggested generalization of complex-analytic spaces then I have no doubt that one has to do real work to make sure that such objects have reasonable properties; e.g., is there a "nowhere dense" analytic set away from which it's a complex-analytic space? Is there a good local/global theory of irred. components?...