# "Étalification" of a scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a scheme. Does the forgetful functor

$$\mathrm{EtSch}/X \to \mathrm{Sch}/X$$

have a right adjoint $Z \mapsto \tilde{Z}$? One might call $\tilde{Z}$ the étalification of $Z$. So this is an étale $X$-scheme together with an $X$-morphism $\tilde{Z} \to Z$, which induces for every étale $X$-scheme $Y$ a bijection $\hom_X(Y,\tilde{Z}) \cong \hom_X(Y,Z)$.

If $X$ is the spectrum of a field $k$, the answer is yes, using 1) the equivalence of sites between étale $k$-schemes and continuous $G$-sets, where $G$ is the absolute Galois group of $k$, 2) the fact that every sheaf on $G$-sets is representable. Explicitly: If $Z$ is a $k$-scheme, let us denote by $Z_{\mathrm{sep}}$ the subset of all points $z \in Z$ such that $k(z)/k$ is finite and separable. Then
$$\tilde{Z} = \coprod\limits_{z \in Z_{\mathrm{sep}}} \mathrm{Spec}(k(z)).$$
For example, $\widetilde{\mathbb{A}^1}=\coprod_{\alpha \in k} \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ and $\widetilde{\mathbb{A}^2}$ is the coproduct of spectra of the form $(k[x]/(p)[T])/(q)$, where $p \in k[x]$ is irreducible and $q$ is some irreducible separable polynomial over $k[x]/(p)$.

Perhaps this construction is well-known, therefore I've put the reference request tag.

Comment: This is reminding me of Stein factorization, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Why do you care that it be a scheme and not just an algebraic space? 

Comment: Any answer about the right adjoint from etale algebraic spaces over X to algebraic spaces over X is also appreciated. 

Comment: You allude to the question: "Is the espace étalé of an étale sheaf a scheme?" Over a base of dimension 0, you answer yes. I believe it is also so in dimension 1. But in dimension 2, no: 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43542/is-this-true-that-algebraic-spaces-etale-and-surjective-over-a-scheme-is-a-scheme

This leaves the question of whether the additional assumption of the sheaf coming from a scheme makes the espace étalé a scheme.

Answer (score 7):

Given a scheme $Z$ over $X$, one can consider the sheaf of "sections $X\to Z$". More precisely, that sheaf associates to every étale open $U\to X$ the set of commutative diagrams
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & Z \\\
& \nearrow & \downarrow \\\
U & \to & X
\end{matrix}
$$
The scheme $\tilde Z$ you are looking for is the *espace étalé* of the above sheaf, a <s>highly non-separated</s> scheme.

Comment: Every sheaf on the small etale site is representable by an algebraic space etale over the base. Is it true that if the original sheaf is the sheaf of sections for a morphism of schemes that this algebraic space is a scheme?

Comment: @André: This is basically just a reformulation of the question. Why is your sheaf represented by an étale *scheme*?

Comment: @Martin: I think Andre's point is that the sheaf "sections of $X \to Z$" is a Zariski-sheaf, i.e. a sheaf over the underlying topological space of $X,$ and then one can form the \'etal\'e space of this sheaf of sets, which is space over $X$ via a local homeomorphism, and one can pull the structure sheaf of $X$ back along this local homeomorphism, to get a locally ringed space locally isomorphic to $X,$ hence it is also a scheme.

Comment: So what is the definition of $\tilde{Z}$?

Comment: @David: Taking the espace etale of the Zariski sheaf certainly gives the wrong answer. If $X$ is a nontrivial etale cover of $Z$ then it has no Zariski sections, yet obviously a functor that takes it to the empty set is not adjoint. 

Comment: @Will: This is certainly true, and it made me wary of the answer. However, perhaps this is just an abuse of terminology, and "espace etale" doesn't mean what it usually does (as it only applies to the open cover topology of a locale). Perhaps it's also customary to call an algebraic space etale over $X$ which represents an etale sheaf, the sheaf's "espace etale". If so, I'll wait for Andre to explain why in this case, its not only an algebraic space, but a scheme.

Comment: I see your point about needing to show that my $\tilde Z$ is a scheme and not just an algebraic space. Schemes can be thought of as algebraic spaces with enough Zariski-local sections of their structure sheaf  (enough to separate points). Since my algebraic space $\tilde Z$ comes equipped with a monomorphism to the scheme $Z$, and the latter has enough Zariski-local sections of its structure sheaf, I would guess that $\tilde Z$ also has enough Zariski-local sections of its structure sheaf, and hence is a scheme. Is this an argument, or am I fooling myself?

Comment: If Z is $\mathbb A^2$ with the obvious projection to $X=\mathbb A^1$ over, for simplicity, an algebraically closed field $k$, then a closed point of the espace etale is an $x$ coordinate, a $y$ coordinate, and a polynomial $f(x,y)$ with those roots whose $y$-derivative is nonzero at that point. A closed point of $Z$ is just an $x$ coordinate and a $y$ coordinate. How is that a monomorphism? If it is, why is it obvious that the other Zariski-local sections exist?

Comment: I was trying to get an argument of the following type to work: Assume $X$ is normal, then etale covers of $X$ are ireducible. Fix a point $P\in Z$, and look at all the maps over $X$ from an etale cover of $X$ to $Z$ whose generic point maps to $P$. If you can show that all of these factor through a single etale cover of $X$, take the disjoint union of those and you're done. If that's true it should be relatively elementary, but my argument for it was becoming too messy. I'm not sure how this argument would extend to the non-normal case.

Comment: @Will Sawin: point taken. It's not a monomorphism.
One could try to argue the other way around, and try to find a map from an algebraic space (not a scheme) to $\mathbb A^m$, such that the projection to $\mathbb A^n$ ($n<m$) is everywhere étale. If such an example exists, then that would answer in the negative the original question of Martin. But somehow, I don't believe that such a thing exists...

Comment: Ok. I think that I have an argument about why there are enough functions on $\tilde Z$. The map $\tilde Z\to Z$ is maybe not a monomorphism, but it has enough features of a monomorphism. More precisely, given two points $x,y\in \tilde Z$, there exists a function $f\in\mathcal O(U)$ (defined on some Zariski open $U\subset Z$) such that the higher directional derivatives of $f$ distinguish $x$ and $y$. I think that this at least deals with the case $\mathbb A^m\to \mathbb A^n$. Can the argument be adapted to work in general?

Comment: I think so. The higher directional derivatives are really coming from a section of the sheafification of $Z$, and they define a map from the local ring at a point of $Z$ to the etale local ring at the profinite completion of the local ring of the point of $X$ it lies over, which must pass through the etale local ring. Agreement of maps to the etale local ring gives local agreement of sections, and local agreement means they're glued together in the espace etale, so they give the same point in the algebraic space. Does that sound good?

Comment: @André: For me your answer is still just a reformulation of my question. You write down the sheaf represented by the scheme we are looking for, and then claim that it is a scheme. You don't offer any proof. Meanwhile I wonder about all the upvotes ... does this mean that I am too blind to see the answer?

Comment: On the upvotes: Perhaps they are based on the idea of hitting functions pulled back from $Z$ with differential operators pulled back from $X$ to distinguish every pair of points. On the highly non-separatedness: I think this will be caused by $X$ being non-normal. Indeed, considering the case of two lines meeting at a point was the inspiration for my current (attempted) answer. But if $X$ is normal and $Z \to X$ is separated, I think $\bar{Z}$ might be separated.

Answer (score 2):

Can we just do this the hard way?

First we construct the set of points of the etalification $\bar{Z}$. A point of the etalification is a point $P$ of $X$ plus a map from the spectrum $T$ of the etale local ring at $X$ to $Z$ that forms a commutative diagram with the natural map $T \to X$. (or, if $Z \to X$ is not finite type, we need to use a finitely-generated subring of the etale local ring.)

Then for $Y\to X$ is etale with a map $Y \to Z$. We get a set-theoretic map $Y \to \bar{Z}$. One easily checks that each point is in the image of such a map. We form the finest topology such that the image of each such map is open.

Now we need a sheaf of rings.  The natural map $\bar{Z} \to Z$ given by taking the image of the special fiber is continuous. Pull back the structure sheaf of $Z$, mod out by the functions on a set $U$ that are $0$ in the images of the open balls $T$ corresponding to the points of $U$, and sheafify.

We will check that this is a scheme by finding affine neighborhoods of each point. Each point of $\bar{Z}$ is in the image of some etale $Y\to X$, and we can further choose $Y$ to be affome amd $T \to Z$ an immersion. We will check that $T \to \bar{Z}$ is an inclusion of locally-ringed spaces. Clearly it is injective. Next we check that it is continuous and open. Open subsets of $\bar{Z}$ wil come from other etale maps which agree on some etale local ring, but then these must agree on an open subset, so they will give open subsets of $Y$. Open subsets of $Y$ are just more schemes etale over $X$.

Then we check it gives an isomorphism of sheaves of rings. The sheaf of rings on $Y$ is the pullback of the sheaf of rings of $Z$, mod the functions that vanish on it. But the functions that vanish on $Y$ are exactly the functions that vanish on each etale local rings, so the two sheaves of rings are identical.

So in addition $\bar{Z}$ is etale over $X$. By construction of the sheaf of rings, $\bar{Z} \to Z$ is a morphism. Similarly the set-theoretic maps $Y \to \bar{Z}$ for all $Y\to Z$ etale over $X$ are clearly morphisms, and give the required bijections.

Obviously this is quite sketchy and there are a lot of technical details I'm missing but it seems doable.